# Python displaying same value within a looped list. 

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm sure I worded the question incorrectly, but here goes...
I have a list of conferences being displayed in conference_list.html as well as the amount of attendees. . They're titles show up fine... However, the amount of attendees are the same for every conference.

```
Conference 1        Attendees 2
Conference 2        Attendees 2
Conference 3        Attendees 2 
Conference 4        Attendees 2
```

Conference 4 is the only conference that has 2 attendees. The others have different amounts.

Views.py:

```
@login_required
def conference_list(request):
    try:
        session_notification = request.session['notification']
        del(request.session['notification'])
    except:
        session_notification = None

    PAGE_SIZE = 20#number of conferences per page
    page = int(request.GET.get('page', 1))
    upper_bound = page * PAGE_SIZE - 1
    lower_bound = (page - 1) * PAGE_SIZE

    context = base_context(request)
    network = context['network']

    conferences = Conference.objects.all()
    second = []
    result = []
    counter = 0

    for conference in conferences:
        is_attending = False
        if counter < lower_bound or counter > upper_bound:
            counter += 1
            result.append(None)
            continue
        result_item = {}
        result_item['conference'] = conference
        result.append(result_item)
        counter += 1

        attendees = conference.investors.all()
        count = attendees.count()
        if request.user in attendees:
            is_attending = True

        context['attendees'] = attendees
        context['is_attending'] = is_attending
        context['count'] = count

    context['current'] = 'conferences'
    context['conferences'] = result

    return render_to_response('conference_list.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template:

```
{% for conference in conferences %}
     <p>{{ conference.conference.name }}</p><span>{{ count }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Why is this happening? Why can't I display the proper amount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your count variable only holds the last value, since you simply overwrite it on each iteration of your loop in your view. Try `result_item['conferences']['count'] = count` and move the line `result.append(result_item)` after it. Adjust your template accordingly.

Comment: `Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 
conferences`

Comment: @Modelesq So, you want Burhan to write your exact code for you?

Comment: @Modelesq Read it. What does it say?

Comment: @Marcin The traceback is exactly that line of code Burhan recommended.

Comment: @Modelesq It's your responsibility to take example code, and fit it to your code. Burhan's recommendation is correct. It's your turn to use it. Don't come here asking people to actually write your code for you. Use the information in the error message to fix your code. It's all there if you spend even a moment engaging with what it is telling you.

Comment: +1 - I bet adding that line of code, seeing the `KeyError` and adding the comment with it was all well within 5 minutes.